# How to collect all fields annotated with @RequestParam into one object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I would like to gather all of my query parameters into a pojo and perform additional validation of the fields.

I have read that I can simply create an object and spring-boot will automatically set those request parameters on it.

`@GetMaping
public ResponseEntity<?> listEntities(@RequestParam(value = "page-number", defaultValue = "0") @Min(0) Integer pageNumber,
@RequestParam(value = "page-size", defaultValue = "100") @Min(1) Integer pageSize ... )`

I am thinking to create a class called `RequestParamsDTO`, where I'd have my query params responsible for the pagination.

But in order to have those fields set on the `RequestParamsDTO`, I'd have to match the name of the request param with the field name. But it won't be a valid variable name: `page-size`.

There must be some workaround, similar to `@RequestParam`'s value attribute, that would set given request param on my field in the DTO.

Please advise.

Comment: Not sure if this will work. Try with `@JsonProperty("page-size")`

Comment: Why don't you set them all in the request body as json and then use a POJO to map it in the controller using @RequestBody

Comment: Because it is not rest-y to submit a payload on GET request, therefore the query parameters

Comment: I tried `@JsonProperty`, it doesn't work

Comment: I can't believe there is no mechanism for it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone already purposed this [feature](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21770#) before such that you can do the following .But unfortunately it is declined due to inactivity response :

```
public class RequestParamsDTO{
   @RequestParam(value="page-number",defaultValue="0")
   @Min(0)
   private Integer pageNumber;

   @RequestParam(value = "page-size", defaultValue = "100") 
   @Min(1) 
   Integer pageSize 
}
```

The most similar things that you can do is using its `@ModelAttribute` which will resolve the parameter in the following [orders](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args):

> - From the model if already added by using Model.
> - From the HTTP session by using @SessionAttributes.
> - From a URI path variable passed through a Converter (see the next    example).
> - From the invocation of a default constructor.
> - From the invocation of a “primary constructor” with arguments that match to Servlet request parameters. Argument names are determined through JavaBeans @ConstructorProperties or through runtime-retained parameter names in the bytecode.

That means the `RequestParamsDTO` cannot not have any default constructor (constructor that is without arguments) .It should have a "primary constructor" which you can use `@ConstructorProperties` to define which request parameters are mapped to the constructor arguments :

```
public class RequestParamsDTO{
    @Min(0)
    Integer pageNumber;
    @Min(1)
    Integer pageSize;

    @ConstructorProperties({"page-number","page-size"})
    public RequestParamsDTO(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
        this.pageNumber = pageNumber != null ? pageNumber : 0;
        this.pageSize = pageSize != null ? pageSize : 100;
    }
}
```

And the controller method becomes:

```
@GetMaping
public ResponseEntity<?> listEntities(@Valid RequestParamsDTO request){

}
```

Notes:

- There is no equivalent annotation for `@RequestParam` 's `defaultValue`,so need to implement in the constructor manually.
- If the controller method argument does not match the values in [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods) , it will resolved as `@ModelAttribute` even though `@ModelAttribute` is not annotated on it explicitly.

Comment: have you actually tried it yourself? `@RequestParam` is not allowed on the field, it is limited to method params only.https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.java

Comment: I wish that would've been that simple.

Comment: I will try `@ConstructorProperties({"page-number","page-size"})` and report back!

Comment: I do not think `@ConstructorProperties` is gonna work here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html

Comment: Seems they surve a different purpose here.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, just fully and completely re-read your reply. Where should you apply `@ModelAttribute` annotation? I tried playing with it and no luck, but I might've missed the point.

Comment: Could you pls provide an example showcasing the usage of both `@ModelAttribute` and `@ConstructorProperties`?

Comment: @IhorM. I have already shown you the example in the answer. I do not annotate with `@ModelAttribute` as I relies on the fact that it will fallback to the `@ModelAttribute`  if the controller method parameter cannot be resolved .You can annotate `@ModelAttribute`  before `RequestParamsDTO` parameter in the controller method if you want to make it explicitly. Also , one important point is that you have to make sure `RequestParamsDTO` cannot have a default parameter (i.e constructor that is without arguments)

Answer (score -2):

To be honest this seems like a lot of effort for a functionality that exists already in spring-boot. You can either extend your repositories from `PagingAndSortingRepository` and have pagination added whenever you call a collection resource.

Or you can write a custom query method (or overwrite an existing one) and add this:

```
Page<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
```

This way spring boot will automatically add all those parameters you want to the Request.

Comment: Pagination query parameters were given as an example and should not be considered literally. I have a bunch of query parameters that I want to group in the DTO and then perform a validation based on their values.