# Spring Rest - deserialize nested object by Jackson

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

we are using javascript library which send parameters like this:

```
datatable[pagination][page]: 1
datatable[pagination][pages]: 
datatable[pagination][perpage]: 10
datatable[sort][sort]: asc
datatable[sort][field]: title
w_id: 6453111
```

here is full GET url"

> http://localhost:8081/foo/bar?datatable%5Bpagination%5D%5Bpage%5D=-2&datatable%5Bpagination%5D%5Bpages%5D=&datatable%5Bpagination%5D%5Bperpage%5D=20&datatable%5Bsort%5D%5Bfield%5D=title&datatable%5Bsort%5D%5Bsort%5D=desc&datatable%5Bquery%5D=&pagination%5Bpage%5D=-2&pagination%5Bpages%5D=&pagination%5Bperpage%5D=20&sort%5Bfield%5D=title&sort%5Bsort%5D=desc&query=&w_id=6453111

encoded as query parameters. We are not able to modify it, so I want write DTO object to deserialize this parameters in elegant way. Is possible to do it in Jackson?

My Dto should lookes like that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class DataDto {
   private Pageable pageable;

   private String wId;
}
```

Comment: Whart do yuo mean by saying `deserialize this parameters` Jackson doesn't enter in joke when you try to get query string parameters..

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I mean when on my controller comes these parameters, I would have as parameter in controller one dto object, which will be filled automaticaly (with some annotations or something like that)

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking - are these literally the names of your request parameters? But this probably answers your question (you can use the `@ConstructorParameters` annotation to map your request parameter names to the constructor arguments. [How to collect all fields annotated with @RequestParam into one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468760/how-to-collect-all-fields-annotated-with-requestparam-into-one-object)

Comment: how do you make the request to your controller? please provide the body of you request or url with query string.

Comment: @zpavel Hi, I added full request URL

Comment: ok and how do you create the javascript array?