# Spring MVC - Query param with hyphens in name in POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

My Spring Boot Application has an API - GET : /employee

And request can have query params like (ALL with dash in the variable name) - first-name, last-name, phone-number, zip-code etc.

I also have to do sanity JAVAX validation( `@Size`, `@Pattern` etc. ) on these parameters, so I am consuming these params in a EmployeeRequest POJO ex. `@Valid EmployeeRequest bean`.

But in have variable names are not allowed with hyphens, so its not working.

I can do this by using - 
   `@RequestParam(value = "first-name,required = false) String firstName`

But by doing so, my controller method will have tens of arguments and I have to Javax validation explicitly, so I am trying to do using Request POJO.

Please provide the advise how we handle it where we have multiple query param with hyphens in name and needs Javax validation in Spring Boot application.

Comment: please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16942352/8112217

Comment: No, in my case, query params have the hyphen(-) in the field names.   So question  is how to have such field names in the Request POJO.

Comment: you can try `@ConstructorProperties({"first-name","last-name"})` -https://stackoverflow.com/a/56470652/8112217

Comment: Thank you @tsarenkotxt, @ConstructorProperties()  worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Soem code would make your question a bit easier to understand however is seems that you are looking for the following:

```
public class EmployeeRequest{

   @JsonProperty("first-name")
   private String firstName;

   @JsonProperty("last-name")
   private String lastName;

}
```

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html

> Defines name of the logical property, i.e. JSON object field name to
>   use for the property.

Comment: I tried this already this does not work,  @ConstructorProperties() on POJO constructor worked for me.

Comment: It works for Response bean using following implementation - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2739